# Which step has exactly 2014 squares

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I am given this picture and asked which step has exactly 2014 squares.

Step 1 has 1 square, and 2014/1=2014

Step 2 has 4 squares, and 2014/4 = 503.5

Step 3 has 7 squares, and 2014/7 = 287.7

Step 4 has 10 squares, and 2014/10 = 20.14

Since the only whole number is 2014, the answer would be step 1.

Is this correct?

Comment: I believe the question is asking you to consider Step 5, Step 6, Step 7, and so on, to determine when the pattern eventually includes 2014 squares.

Answer (score 4):

The question means to ask you to consider the pattern and determine which step will have 2014 squares. By inspection, the $n$th step has $3n-2$ squares. So you want $3n-2=2014$ which gives $n=672$. So it's step 672.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an arithmetic progression (one with a common difference between each terms). So we have the following sequence of the number of cubes in each pattern:

1,4,7,10...

From this, we can see that there is a common difference of 3, and using this following definition for the nth term of an arithmetic sequence:

$u_n=a_1+(n-1)d$ where $d$ is the common difference and $a_1$ is the first term, we get:

$u_n=1+(n-1)(3)=1+3n-3=3n-2$

Setting this equal to 2014 should give us the step that we want.

$2014=3n-2$, so n=672, therefore the answer is step 672.